# Удаление элемента из односвязного списка путём смещения

Tags: golang, структуры-данных

Есть struct следующего вида:

```
type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}
```

В него записаны следующие данные:

```
0xc000104220&{1 0xc000104230}
0xc000104230&{2 0xc000104240}
0xc000104240&{3 0xc000104250}
0xc000104250&{3 <nil>}
```

`DeleteDuplicates` сравнивает между собой все элементы массива по полю `Val` и если находит похожие должен сдвинуть цепочку на месте дубликата.

```
func (ln *ListNode) DeleteDuplicates() {

LOOP:
    for e1 := ln; e1 != nil; e1 = e1.Next {
        for e2 := e1.Next; e2 != nil; e2 = e2.Next {
            if e1.Val == e2.Val {
                e1 = e1.Next //Должен перезаписывать ln
                goto LOOP
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В моём представлении e1 должен затереться ссылкой e1.Next, и всё это должно отражается на ln, так как e1 содержит ссылку на элемент ln, но вместо этого просто меняется значение e1. Скорее всего, я неправильно использую переменные со ссылкой, так как если написать в грубую `ln.Next = ln.Next.Next` это сработает.

Код на goplay если нужно: https://goplay.space/#CYWdOSI3DLM

Comment: `*e1 = *e1.Next`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov не понимаю почему, но это работает. Просто вроде `var e1 *ListNode = ln` и так хранит в себе ссылку. Отправите ответ что бы можно было отметить вопрос как решённый?

Comment: `e1` - это переменная-указатель. `e1 = e1.Next` - записать в переменную-указатель новый адрес. `*e1` - это структура, на которую указывает указатель. `*e1 = *e1.Next` - записать в структуру новые поля.

Comment: `e1 = e1.Next` если бы это работало так, как ты ожидаешь, то как бы ты итерировался? Ты ведь такое же присваивание делаешь ещё в инкременте цикла `for` - оно бы тебе весь список записало бы в первый элемент

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Думаю я понял. Мы обращается к переменной со *, что бы изменить участок памяти на который она указывает, а я просто менял место на которое указывала переменная. Иногда смотришь на людей, и не понимаешь почему они так тупят в простых вещах... а потом сам... кхм.